# Update element with ajax don't affect until for loop end

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, long-integer

I want to print a lot of numbers ONE-BY-ONE with AJAX.

something like this: (each new line is update of previous line!)

```
output is:
    1
    12
    123
    1234
    12345
    123456
    ...
```

I tried a lot and read a lot of this same problem, but i couldn't find my right Answer.

The real problem is every FOR LOOP in javascript will NO affect the DOM after it will END the loop. I just want update the DOM inside the FOR LOOP while working on a long running job.

Please look at my code.

```js
$("#btn").on("click", dowork);

function dowork() {
  document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "working";
  setTimeout(function() {
    var counter = 100; // i want assign counter = 2000000000
    for (var i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
      document.getElementById("print_here").innerHTML += i;
    }
    document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "done!";
  }, 50);
}
```

```css
#btn {
  background: #1f1f1f;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #fff;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#print_here {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="btn">CLICK TO DO WORK</div>
<div id="foo"></div>
<div id="print_here"></div>
```

Thanks for any answer and help to solve this problem.

Comment: javascript is very fast. its updating at each loop step but you won't realise. How do you want the output to appear like? in 1s interval?

Comment: @NGM As Stackoverflow works differently to forums which usually use the `[Solved]` prefix I edited your question, as `Petter` said, the accepted answers show already that it is solved and what solved it. Stackoverflow also uses color coding on search results so users can easily see which question have accepted answers.

Comment: @Nope Thank you. OK i got it. Best Wishes for you and the other Stackoverflow Big Masters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your DOM is "locked" while it is being updated and redrawn ones the loop is done. You can free up the resource to let the DOM update each time wrapping your DOM change in a `setTimeout`, similar to:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("print_here").innerHTML += i;
},1);
```

To ensure `setTimeout` uses the correct value for `i` use `let i` instead of `var i`

```js
$("#btn").on("click", dowork);

function dowork() {
  document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "working";

  var counter = 3000; // i want assign counter = 2000000000
  for (let i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("print_here").innerHTML += i;
    }, 1);
  }
  document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "done!";
}
```

```css
#btn {
  background: #1f1f1f;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #fff;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#print_here {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="btn">CLICK TO DO WORK</div>
<div id="foo"></div>
<div id="print_here"></div>
```

> I want change the #foo into "done!" after the FOR statement is END

You could check if you are at your last item you process within the `setTimeout`, similar to:

```
if (i == counter - 1){
    document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "done!";
}
```

```js
$("#btn").on("click", dowork);

function dowork() {
  document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "working";

  var counter = 3000; // i want assign counter = 2000000000
  for (let i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("print_here").innerHTML += i;
      if (i == counter - 1){
        document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "done!";
      }
    }, 1);
  }
}
```

```css
#btn {
  background: #1f1f1f;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #fff;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#print_here {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="btn">CLICK TO DO WORK</div>
<div id="foo"></div>
<div id="print_here"></div>
```

Comment: Dear Nope, I want change the #foo into "done!" after the FOR statement is END. please help me to solve it too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to let the call stack complete so the browser can do its work on the page.  If you bog down the one main thread, page updates aren't going to occur.

One way to do this is use setImmediate or nextTick.  This is non-standard, so check this polyfill:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-next-tick

Basically, you do an iteration, then tell the browser to do the next iteration as soon as possible... and this occurs on a fresh call stack.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the working code for you:

```js
$("#btn").on("click", dowork);

function dowork() {
  document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "working";
  setTimeout(function() {

    var i, j, row = 5;
    var html = "";
    for (i = 1; i <= row; i++) {
      for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        html += "<span>" + j + "</span>";
      }
      html += "</br>";
    }
    console.log(html);
    document.getElementById("print_here").innerHTML = html;
  }, 50);
}
```

```css
#btn {
  background: #1f1f1f;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #fff;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#print_here {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="btn">CLICK TO DO WORK</div>
<div id="foo"></div>
<div id="print_here"></div>
```

**Rows** is the number of rows you want to print.

Comment: This still locks up the browser. You are using `row=5` which is hiding the problem. Set it to `row=600` to see the DOM not being updated until the loop is done. What OP wants is the DOM being update with **each** row being written and not when the loop is complete.